# Creación de clases parac onfigurar todo tipo de controles una sola vez (Datagridview, botones, textbox, ect)

Tags: c#

En el mi desarrollo de una aplicación de escritorio en c# vana ver muchos controles como Datagridview, botones, textbox, ect y no se si crear una sola clase para configurar cada uno de los controles solo una vez y llamarlos como un método, así en el futuro si quiero cambiar la apariencia de cualquier control solo tengo que ir a l archivo de configuración y hacerlo. Ahora bien no si se eso se hace en una clase aparte o se crea una biblioteca con este tipo de configuraciones.

No me gustaría estar cambiando todos los forms o todas las características de los controles muchas veces ya que si es solo un Datagridview muy fácil pero si son 20 y se crean en tiempo de ejecución.

Windows form no WPf.

Cabe aclarar que todo esto en en Visual Studio 2019 - C#.

Comment: si es wpf los estilos se pueden definir a nivel del sistema... lo que tenes que aclarar es si es wpf, uwp, winforms.. e igual, tu pregunta es basada en opiniones....

Comment: Seria Windows Form.

Comment: entonces mi mejor consejo (y es una opinion) es que lo pases a wpf... igual, sigue siendo basada en opiniones...

Comment: Pero en windows form como se haría?